# Do all events have a listeners array or is it rather that all "emitters" have a listeners array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking through the node documentation and trying to understand this function

```
server.on('connection', (stream) => {
  console.log('someone connected!');
});

emitter.on(eventName, listener)
```

The part I'm confused about is this; the specific part is bolded. "Adds the listener function to the end of the listeners array **for** the event named eventName. "

Does the for mean there is a listeners array for all emitters (which in this case is server) and just that some of those functions in that array are "for" (as in designated to) certain events. Or, does it mean, that there is a listeners array for all events and that it will just add this function (stream) to the event which is, 'connection'.

If it's the latter, how does the eventlistenerarray[lastindex aka (stream)] know that it's only running when the event is happening on the emmiter... server in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL; TR:**

_each object you attach events to store their own events (independently from other objects)

_each event name has its own array of (ordered) functions (independently from other events in the same object)

**Details:**

You have a good exemple of how it is structured and stored in [this section of the Node documentation on events](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_passing_arguments_and_this_to_listeners)

```
const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
myEmitter.on('myEvent', function(a, b) {
  console.log(a, b, this, this === myEmitter);
  // Prints:
  //   a b MyEmitter {
  //     domain: null,
  //     _events: { myEvent: [Function] },
  //     _eventsCount: 1,
  //     _maxListeners: undefined } true
});
myEmitter.emit('myEvent', 'a', 'b');
```

You can see that when `this` (the object to which the event has been attached) is logged, the events handlers are stored inside the object itself (in the property `_events`). It is of the form of an object where all events names are the keys, and the value is an array of all the functions attached to the event. The fact it's an array here is important, because functions will be called syncronously and in the order they have been added.

Comment: so when an event is "emit"ed through the .emit method, it traverses the "emitter" object looking for a propert called _events: and then calls all events {eventX: [Function]} that are within the arrays, and those which are separated by commas. 

In this case it is an anonymous function called { event: [Function]}, had we duplicated the myEmitter.on('even't, function(a,b).....cont....... there should be two "[Functions]" associated with the 'event' event on the emitter object. How does [Function] link to the (or how does node know) to link to the anonymous functions listed esp if there are 2

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you meant, but not everything in `_events` is called. When you call `.emit`, the first parameter is the event name (I have edited to `myEvent` as event name in the answer to be clearer). It will first check if there is a property `myEvent` in `_events` and will call only the functions in this array. In the array is saved the direct reference to the function that was bound to the event by the `.on` call, so Node can just call the array element, you can think it as if the whole function is saved in the array (...)

Comment: You're not obliged to use an anonymous function, you can use a named function that was declared before, in that case the log would show `[Function: nameOfTheFunction]`.

Comment: I guess what I meant was what if there is more than one anonymous function? How are they differentiated?

Comment: The same way than usually (like for `setTimeout`, callbacks etc), each anonymous function creates its own reference in memory. If you duplicate the code `myEmitter.on('even't, function(a,b){ })` actually 2 separate references of function are created in memory, even if it's the exact same code.

Answer (score 0):

The emitter (in this case the server) keeps track of all attached event listeners, there is no global event listeners array.